# Converting tar.gz, etc. to deb

Tags: deb, tar, convert

I was wondering if it is safe and/or advisable to convert "zipped" files to "deb"?  Same zipped files require extensive terminal usage just to attempt to install and mistakes can be easily made.  I have "Alien" installed.  For example, Mozilla, when it releases a new version, does not generate a "deb" version. Instead, it is "zipped" and requires a lengthy terminal install.  So, can I use Alien to convert the zipped file/app to "deb"?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge , you can only use alien with other package management types, such as rpm package. Thus, I highly doubt itbis possible with a file archive such as zip ( not unless the file contains all necessary data required for making a deb )

Answer (score 1):

the installation will fail if you just convert the package to deb...
it's not so hard. you download it, extract it and inside that folder you open a terminal and do what we all do:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

It's only 3 commands.
As for firefox , there is a ppa that does your life easier.
If you still want to go for the manual procedure and do it yourself , then you must understand "how to".
All apps executables go to /usr/bin , the /opt folder is just a folder to remember where the manually installed apps are. For example you could just install an app on desktop and link the executable there. 
So in other words you move the app in /opt and the executable in /usr/bin and link it to the app. It's simple already and can't be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo apt install alien
$ alien packagename.tar.gz whatyouwantthedebnametobe.deb
```

Example:

```
$ alien ige.tar.gz ige.deb
```

Then you can install `gdebi`:

```
$ sudo apt install gdebi
```

Then <kbd>right-click</kbd> the .deb package and open with `gdebi` and click *Install* in the `gdebi` installer.

There you go.

Then you can open it in your apps.

Answer (score 0):

on my Ubuntu

$ sudo apt install alien
$ sudo alien -d your_file.tar.gz

you will  have this file

your_file.deb
then install it