# Can I install Thunderbird 115 as a .deb package?

Tags: apt, thunderbird

I'm using Kubuntu 23.04, do not use Snaps, and wish to update to Thunderbird 115 from the installed version 102. Is this possible? It appears as if Ubuntu have stopped providing non-Snap packages for mainstream apps and Thunderbird themselves offer me a tar.bz2 whilst I'd rather use packaged apps.

Will Thunderbird 115 be available as an official .deb file at all; will it be in the repos? What's the best non-Snap way to install it and keep it updated?

Comment: I've seen installing using [alien](https://askubuntu.com/q/772109/29073) but when I do that -- `fakeroot alien -d thunderbird.tar.bz2; sudo apt install ./thunderbird.deb` -- I end up with thunderbird directly below root directory and all the links get broken, etc.. It runs but it's a pain, I'll need to manually futz with it to get things installed right.

Comment: You can try the thunderbird beta ppa (https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/thunderbird-next), which has Thunderbird 115. The stable PPA for thunderbird still has v102, but it will be eventually updated. https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easy add the official PPA for Thunderbird beta by adding ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next to your system to get Thunderbird 115.

```shell
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next
sudo apt update
```

Worked fine for me.

Link: [https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/thunderbird-next](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/thunderbird-next)

Comment: So, Thunderbird-Next is a beta release channel, as of now they have 1:115.1.1+build2-0ubuntu0.23.04.1~mt1 , which is a little strange to me as the thunderbird.net website offers thunderbird-115.1.1.tar.bz2, ie the 115.1.1 release; so I can't see why TB-Next isn't offering a later beta, I guess there isn't one. I was hoping for a release just packaged as a deb. @vanadium suggested a different mozillateam repo, they have 1:102.14.0+build1-0ubuntu0.23.04.1~mt1 (and for 23.10, etc.) which is stated to be a stable build, but obviously not as current as I'm hoping for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: FWIW I see `1:115.2.0+build2-0ubuntu0.23.04.1~mt1` is still the latest available from TB-Next.

Answer (score 3):

The mozilla team provides a [PPA for stable releases of Firefox ESR and Thunderbird](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). So yes, adding this PPA will allow you to have installed the latest Thunderbird and keep it automatically updated. At some point, the PPA will be updated to contain Thunderbird 115.

Comment: The question was really whether any official source had Thunderbird for Ubuntu at release date(s). I'll try thunderbird-next as that may be what I'm after.

Comment: As usual, the newer version will ship with a newer release of Ubuntu. The only exception where a deb package was always upgraded to the latest release was Firefox, but now this is shipped as a snap.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it!
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1418372

I am now looking for a way to restore Tbird 102.x to ubuntu (like you - no snaps). So far I, too, only have the tar.bz2 file that Mozilla provides:
https://archive.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/

Wish I'd looked at where tbird was installed before I purged it...

if you must upgrade, this might help.  There are several resources out there with more details (from which I created by install notes). 
[https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) 
from my install notes:

```
*now prep to use the MozillaTeam PPA for firefox (andy maybe Thunderbird, eventually?)
 add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
*now set the priority of the PPA firefox higher than the snap version:
 cat <<_EOF_ | tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozillateamppa
Package: firefox* thunderbird*
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 501
_EOF_

 apt update

*NB - be careful below to watch for snap being re-installed, and quit if it wants to.  The problem is most likely in the 
      configuration of the mozillateamppa, and pinning the higher priority for the ppa version of firefox over the snap version.
*bare bones configuration
  apt install firefox thunderbird
```

Comment: found the answer to my wish -- unzip/untar the .bz2 file into /usr/lib (beside the ff directory).  make a symlink in /usr/bin to the thunderbird executable. (ln -s /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird /usr/bin/thunderbird).  All the existing .desktop launchers I have work fine.  Thunderbird 102 also obeys the "(DO NOT) automatically mark messages as read" directive.