# How add to repositoris new Thunderbirs?

Tags: apt, thunderbird, add-apt-repository

I can't find information how to add new Thunderbird 115 to repositories using apt.
Someone now?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I install Thunderbird 115 as a .deb package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478163/can-i-install-thunderbird-115-as-a-deb-package) Please read also the comments under that question.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1478163/can-i-install-thunderbird-115-as-a-deb-package#comment2588788_1478163